# Optimize query so it does not need a Top N sort

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have the following query

```
select top 25
    tblSystem.systemName,
    tblCompany.name
from 
    tblSystem
    join tblCompany
        on tblSystem.fkCompanyID = tblCompany.pkCompanyID
order by
    tblSystem.systemName, 
    tblCompany.name
```

That generates the first execution plan in the picture, the 2nd is the same query without the `order by`
[image]
Is there any way a can get rid of the `TOP N Sort` (so only a `TOP`  is needed) by indexing the tables in a particular way?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you want to remove the `TOP 25` when you need them?

Comment: @TimSchmelter If I remove the `order by` a `TOP` without sort is done. I want to know if I can index the tables to that the sorting is not needed.

Comment: An [indexed view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982562/optimize-query-so-it-does-not-need-a-top-n-sort) could work, but indexes on separate tables being JOINed won't relieve the need to sort in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add an index to `tblSystem` on `systemName` with `fkCompanyID` included.

```
create index IX_tblSystem_systemName 
  on tblSystem(systemName) include(fkCompanyID)
```

Rewrite your query to pick the 25 first values (with ties) from `tblSystem` in a derived table ordered by `systemName` and then join to `tblCompany` to get the 25 values you need.

Depending on if `fkCompanyID` allows null values or not you need to filter out null values in the where clause in the derived table.

```
select top (25)
  S.systemName,
  C.name 
from (
     select top (25) with ties
       S.fkCompanyID,
       S.systemName
     from tblSystem as S
     where S.fkCompanyID is not null
     order by S.systemName
     ) as S
  inner join tblCompany as C
    on S.fkCompanyID = C.pkCompanyID
order by S.systemName,
         C.name
```

You will still have to top(n) sort operator but it will only sort the 25 rows (+ ties) that you got from the derived table joined against `tblCompany`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get rid of it by having a covering index containing the rows already sorted by systemName ASC, name ASC, but my suspicion is that you're micro-optimizing.  Is this query slow?  If it's fast, then the fact that the "top N sort" takes "half the time" isn't really important.  If it's slow, I'd be much more concerned with the Index Scan even though it's listed as 4%.